# Execute SQL Server 2012 UPDATE one after the other after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have these number of queries that needed to be run one after the other. I am using SQL Server 2012.

The reason for this is that I need a sequence of loop to update the `PAYROLL` after inserting the initial data, and once all the data is updated, I will run another batch of update, thus making another **UPDATE** for it to work, the problem is that all UPDATE queries running at the same time, I need it to run sequentially for me to achieve my goal.

The sequence is as follows

- `INSERT INTO PAYROLL() SELECT...`
- `UPDATE PAYROLL...` Run Update 1 after finishing insert.
- `UPDATE PAYROLL...` Run Update 2 after finishing Update 1
- `UPDATE PAYROLL...` Run Update 3 after finishing Update 2
- `UPDATE PAYROLL...` Run Update 4 after finishing Update 3

And so on, I tried using `GO`, but I'm still getting the same result.

```
INSERT INTO PAYROLL() 
    SELECT...;
GO

UPDATE PAYROLL...;
GO  --  Run Update 1 after finishing insert.

UPDATE PAYROLL...;
GO  -- Run Update 2 after finishing Update 1

UPDATE PAYROLL...;
GO  -- Run Update 3 after finishing Update 2

UPDATE PAYROLL...;
GO  --  Run Update 4 after finishing Update 3
```

But it does not work. Is there a way for this to be executed one after the other aside from `GO`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? Is there an error? What is the output/messages?

Comment: Strange - for me, all queries always run in synchronous way, not in parallel. How do you run those updates? What about transaction isolation level?

Comment: Just try Begin End Blocks and see - suggestion only. I have never come across such. If that doesn't work, make each insert /  update as steps of a job, to be run when each is successfully finished.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, it does not have any error. my only issue is that it's not generating an output the way I wanted it to produce, it should run the query one after the other.

Comment: @Arvo that's what I know as well, I don't understand why it's not running the way it should. Is there a way for force SQL to run in synchronous way?

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage I'll test it again. I'll add BEGIN and END.

Comment: Your deduction of `all UPDATE queries running at the same time` is plain wrong. Even if you went to the extreme length of splitting your code to multiple sessions and ran them at the same time, locks would kick in. Please tell us *why* you think the query are run in parallel, and we'll find what's going on.